# Texas Hold ‘em Rules

Tags: house-rules, poker-texas-holdem

I have recently played some cash games in Las Vegas and I have found that there are a number of unwritten rules that seem to have poor coherence between different players and dealers. Tournament rules seem a bit less nebulous.

Is there a standardized set of rules for Texas Hold ‘em?
Is it a law or does each casino have their own set of rules?

Are they required to have written rules?
If so, could you link me to the rule book?
Any (Las Vegas) casino’s rules will do.

Comment: Could you give an example of some of these "unwritten rules"?

Comment: Almost guarantee that these rules are either written somewhere and you didn't find them, or they're not rules, they're etiquette.

Comment: I think the question is fine, even if not as clearly worded as it could be. Seems like basically the question is "does Texas Hold'em have official rules, or are the rules just a general convention agreed on that people and casinos can decide for themselves?" It's a reasonable question because while games like Monopoly or Catan are officially owned by a specific company with official rules created by that company, most traditional card games tend to work differently.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst this can not be exhaustive, every casino I've played in (this is UK, not USA) has had the rules on display somewhere, particularly those concern live play that can't happen on line such as 'string betting/raising'.

In my experience they have all been based on [Robert's Rules Of Poker](https://www.homepokergames.com/roberts-rules-poker.php)

You might also get a better answer/more specific on

> [Poker StackExchange](https://poker.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

The casinos MUST publish AND POST their rules.  There are no such thing as "unwritten" rules.  There may be rules of ettiquitte. If someone does something that is not allowed by the publically posted rules, call attention to the dealer AND if the dealer does nothing to enforce the rules, call the floor manager.

If they do not rule in your favor, cash out your chips & leave the casino immediately.

IF THE DEALER shows he can do majic tricks with the deck, LEAVE THE CASINO IMMEDIATELY after cashing out your chips.

Dealers that have special card tricks & skills can easily give you half ass cards & give their friends the winning cards.

There are MANY, very skilled, card shuffling dealers, so watch out for yourself & your money.